# Setting `device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm making a customized camera app, and I'd like to get the camera input at 60fps (I don't care much about quality) and show it in a UIView.

What I have so far is the following:

```
struct CustomCameraView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let previewView = UIImageView()
        func configureCameraForHighestFrameRate(device: AVCaptureDevice) {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()                
                let fr = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 60)
                device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = fr
                device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = fr                
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("error setting frame rate")
            }
        }
        
        func setupLivePreview() {
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
            videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                captureSession.startRunning()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    videoPreviewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
                }
            }
        }
                
        var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
        var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()        
        guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
            print("Unable to access back camera!")
            return UIImageView()
        }        
        configureCameraForHighestFrameRate(device: backCamera)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
            print("max frame duration on input",
input.device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration)
            
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                setupLivePreview()
            }
        }
        catch let error  {
            print("Error Unable to initialize back camera:  \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        return previewView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {}
}
```

Pretty simple, I access the camera, set its `activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `activeVideoMaxFrameDuration`s and I use a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to replace the `UIImageView`'s `CALayer`.

I've tried changing the `timescale` of `CMTime` to `30`, `20`, `10`, even `1` but it doesn't have any effect. What should I do?

I don't get any errors, and here's my system info:

- iPhone 11 Pro
- XCode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)
- iOS 14.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice) is wrong:

> Directly configuring a capture device’s activeFormat property changes the capture session’s preset to inputPriority.

This is not true, I have to set the capture session's preset to `.inputPriority` for the captured device's configuration to take place. So adding this line solved the problem:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = .inputPriority
```

I've made [a post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664978) at the Apple Developer Forum, hopefully they'll take a look at it.